# vi or Vim: Mac/Iterm 2 highlight-paste

Tags: cut-copy-paste, macos, iterm2

When editing with Vim on Macbook Pro with Iterm2 interface I can copy text by:

1. highlighting text with left-button double click on mouse,
2. paste text by pressing center wheel on mouse.

Instead of (2) I would much prefer pasting the text by right-clicking the mouse button.

A related problem is that when highlighting the text in one window and pasting into another, the active window does not switch from window 1 to window 2; the active window remains window 1 but I would much prefer a switch to window 2.

Is there a way to fix these two problems?

Comment: Also for remapping mouse buttons, keyboard shortcuts and so forth on a Mac, I highly highly recommend http://www.bettertouchtool.net/ (which is free).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a). the copy/paste workflow you are currently using doesn't actually involve Vim: you're using iTerm 2's mouse interface for copy-pasting, b). as such the most appropriate place for changing this functionality is also outside of Vim (and is not actually possible using Vim configuration).

Answer (score 1):

1. Get yourself [a proper Vim](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/releases) with clipboard support.
2. Place the bundled `mvim` script somewhere in your `$PATH`.
3. Add an alias to your `~/.bashrc` or whatever init file is used by your shell:

   ```
   alias vim='/path/to/mvim -v'
   ```
4. Use `"+y` and `"+p` to yank to and put from the system clipboard.